# Typhoon inject xib loaded table cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, typhoon

I’m trying to migrate some of my view controllers and `UITableView` subclasses over to using Typhoon, but I can’t find any documentation around what to do with cells that are generated from a tableView’s `dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

The TableViewController I’m working with uses multiple cell types which it registers with the TableView in `viewDidLoad` using `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifer:`.

What should we do to have Typhoon inject cells loaded from xibs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to create a view assembly for your xib loaded table cells, and make this one of your application assemblies. Assuming you're using [plist integration](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Plist-Integration) then you'd add it to your app's plist as:

```
<key>TyphoonInitialAssemblies</key>
<array>
    <string>ViewProvider</string>
    <string>ApplicationAssembly</string>
    <string>CoreComponentsAssembly</string>
    <string>NetworkAssembly</string>
</array>
```

Logically it would sit to the side of your top-level application assembly.

```
@interface ViewProvider : TyphoonAssembly

//Reference any other assemblies that you need
@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly) CoreComponents *coreComponents;

//Create a definition for the table cell with the injections that need to happen. 
- (UITableViewCell*)myTableViewCell;
```

Next inject this into your view controller.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) InjectedClass(ViewAssembly) viewProvider;

@end 

@implementation MyViewController

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //Load the cell from the XIB first. 
    //And now tell Typhoon to inject it
    [self.viewProvider inject:cell];
    //The above matches by type, you can also provide an @selector() 
    //definition in the assembly

    //Any other config to the cell
    return cell;

}
```

The documentation for this feature is [here](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Activating-Assemblies#instructing-typhoon-to-inject-a-pre-obtained-instance).

Comment: This answer assumes Typhoon 3.0. If you're using Typhoon 2.0, the code will be slightly different (3.0 is backward compatible with 2.0, but the above style is nicer).